# SP 2013 : pdf , word as a new version upload in document library

Tags: 2013

I want to upload documents to a document library . I upload a pdf document first as version 1.0 and latter i want to upload a pptx as a 2.0 version ? I want to add the pptx as a new version to the document of pdf . Is there any way to achieve this ?

Comment: what do you mean with "on top" ?

Comment: Corrected the question . . ..

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately , the versioning features only working for the items with same name and type.

if you need to do that as bad workaround

- you can change the pptx file pdf and upload it but it's not open until change it's extension again
- also you can save it as pdf and upload it with the same name of old file

Check also How to [plan to versioning in SharePoint](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262378.aspx#bkmk_plan_versioning)